# Using variable for current table in MariaDB insert trigger?

Tags: mysql, triggers, mariadb

I am wanting my id field value to take on a random unique value when a new row is inserted. Is it possible to replace the the myvideos table name, in the code below, with a variable representing the table in the current context?

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE next_id INT;
    DECLARE max_int INT;

    SET max_int = 4294967295;
    SET next_id = FLOOR(max_int * RAND());

    WHILE (SELECT id FROM myvideos WHERE id = next_id) DO
        SET next_id = FLOOR(max_int * RAND());
    END WHILE;

    SET NEW.id=next_id;
END
```

I am using MariaDB 10. It is declared as before insert.

Comment: Triggers are executed every time an action is executed on the table (in your example every time you insert a row). Personally, I would save my whole playlist without the randomness and I would shuffle the playlist in my main software. Two possibilities here 1. Before launching the playlist (so the randomness change every time you launch the playlist) . 2. Before changing to the next song/video (that is way closer to a real randomness IMO).

Comment: I have renamed the table in the example, since I am actually using this as a model of a number of my tables. The reason I am wanting a random value for the id is that it is going to be externalised, via a REST API. While I could have an external_id column, the general logic would remain the same. If I didn't care I would just use the auto-increment feature. Now I mention this I wonder whether having an internal_id an external_id would provide any value?

Comment: I just had an idea, what if instead of using a trigger to generate a random index when inserting data, you created a stored procedure to shuffle it before returning the list of videos? A trigger is bounded to a particular table, you won't be able to passed it parameters. On the other hand, you can pass as many parameters (in and out) as you want to a stored procedure. Of course, you simply transfert the performance load from inserting to the fetching, but, as an advantage, your list get reshuffle every time you want it (with another parameter, you also ask not to shuffle the list).

Comment: Please explain _why_ you want a "unique, but random, number".

Comment: Unique, because it will be used as row identifier and random, because I don't want the number sequential, where the id will be present in a public rest API. We don't want inferences made based on the id value, which could be done if the value was sequential - is this unreasonable?